# Filtering strings if certain multiple keyword matches

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am new to python so it is challenging for me to extract lines from a file if certain words matched in that line.

I have an array of html links for eg:
My Input

```
['https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/trackr-rebrands-to-adero-pivots-to-finding-whereabouts-of-groups-of-items/&ct=ga&cd=caeyacotntqymzy0njawnzu2mji3otq0mziazjhmndaxowrjnmviywm4otpjb206zw46vvm&usg=afqjcnebtnj9ybuywkwcp33xlzvkdtqndq', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/will-uber-gobble-up-lime-or-fly-off-with-bird/&ct=ga&cd=caeyasotntqymzy0njawnzu2mji3otq0mziazjhmndaxowrjnmviywm4otpjb206zw46vvm&usg=afqjcnf4upl3v1gzd5a1xr0pgpvc1zedya', 'https://www.google.com/alerts/remove?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=ntqymzy0njawnzu2mji3otq0mw&s=ab2xq4hy_egw7prfejiq3uhjazt-7cjtjoilna0', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=ntqymzy0njawnzu2mji3otq0mw', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=ntqymzy0njawnzu2mji3otq0mw', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/will-uber-gobble-up-lime-or-fly-off-with-bird/&ct=ga&cd=caeyacoumtq0mjmwnzuwmtg3odi4ndq5mtmygjbimdy5nmi3nmjkmwuymdq6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnf4upl3v1gzd5a1xr0pgpvc1zedya', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/hulu-to-top-23-million-subscribers-by-year-end/&ct=ga&cd=caeyasoumtq0mjmwnzuwmtg3odi4ndq5mtmygjbimdy5nmi3nmjkmwuymdq6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnfyn98cfz1e8oyay72qwdchsg_f_q', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/fintech-investors-and-founders-to-judge-startup-battlefield-africa/&ct=ga&cd=caeyaioumtq0mjmwnzuwmtg3odi4ndq5mtmygjbimdy5nmi3nmjkmwuymdq6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnfxredq8rapscoupmhdzbf-husqyw', 'https://www.google.com/alerts/remove?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtq0mjmwnzuwmtg3odi4ndq5mtm&s=ab2xq4hjxw0sqeep2yq6odjmq700btmzyqs3svy', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtq0mjmwnzuwmtg3odi4ndq5mtm', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtq0mjmwnzuwmtg3odi4ndq5mtm', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/podcast-series-c/&ct=ga&cd=caeyacoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcngnd6o3mwrmbj-uc-1a84mlixp26w', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/agricool-raises-another-28-million-to-grow-fruits-in-containers/&ct=ga&cd=caeyasoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnecc5wtp2klzwob021zzcxodrkstg', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/fivetran-announces-15m-series-a-to-build-automated-data-pipelines/&ct=ga&cd=caeyaioumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnfvplce8-juoffflxwe8-ttrqaz_g', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/bios-health/&ct=ga&cd=caeyayoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcngjpzu9t9hyjfjkaf1sefloujvjhq', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/freeletics-raises-45m-for-its-ai-powered-fitness-coach/&ct=ga&cd=caeybcoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcneh-xmavwlbin0hfswkmrbniousnw', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/mixcloud-select/&ct=ga&cd=caeybsoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcneh_kjqkido1dz30dgax2cv1-6g6w', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/atomicos-fourth-state-of-the-european-tech-report-highlights-lots-of-rosy-numbers-but-also-a-discrimination-problem/&ct=ga&cd=caeybioumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnfcgwt_rwsya4ulxw6im7mcy0a74q', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/fortressiq-raises-12m-to-bring-new-ai-twist-to-process-automation/&ct=ga&cd=caeybyoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcngn2mdhvdzsxhjpy9wako015rsd9w', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/birth-control-delivery-startup-nurx-now-offers-an-at-home-hpv-testing-kit/&ct=ga&cd=caeyccoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnhufwynz2xvx8h7y5njesu5umrqbw', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/faraday-future-furloughs-more-employees-as-cash-woes-continue/&ct=ga&cd=caeycsoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcng7ma6lr8xqakdvwbcr9kmgkvhvnw', 'https://www.google.com/alerts/remove?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odg&s=ab2xq4j8dtcluvhhgyayaorwyeut2bkvyp4mrac', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odg', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odg']
```

My expected output should be

```
['https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/agricool-raises-another-28-million-to-grow-fruits-in-containers/&ct=ga&cd=caeyasoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnecc5wtp2klzwob021zzcxodrkstg','https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/freeletics-raises-45m-for-its-ai-powered-fitness-coach/&ct=ga&cd=caeybcoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcneh-xmavwlbin0hfswkmrbniousnw','https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/fortressiq-raises-12m-to-bring-new-ai-twist-to-process-automation/&ct=ga&cd=caeybyoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcngn2mdhvdzsxhjpy9wako015rsd9w']
```

I want to filter links which contains specific keywords likes "any number 0-9", "millions","raises", "funding", "valuations" etc etc.

I have gone through many links in stackoverflow but could not find what I was looking for. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include what have you attempted so far along with your current outputs. Also provide a set of sample inputs and their corresponding outputs

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: No @shrewmouse. I would love using regex but no luck

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: @Rakesh Done , I have added the output and the new input also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
candidates = ['https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/corporate-food-catering-startup-chewse-raises-19-million/&ct=ga&cd=caeyacoumtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mteygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcngcalj2l2089xqyzdr5clovuuvafq', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/sleep-tracking-ring-oura-raises-20-million-from-michael-dell-lance-armstrong-and-others/&ct=ga&cd=caeyasoumtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mteygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcng8wdz35c5krnjcnypbw21b0pihfg', 'https://www.google.com/alerts/remove?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mte&s=ab2xq4j8dtcluvhhgyayaorwyeut2bkvyp4mrac', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mte', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mte']

def interesting(text):
    text = text.lower()
    if any([word in text for word in ['billions', 'funding', 'valuations'] + ['%dm' % i for i in range(10)]]):
            return True

    # Add other conditions

    return False

result = list(filter(interesting, candidates))
print(result)
```

The output for this example is:

```
['https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/corporate-food-catering-startup-chewse-raises-19-million/&ct=ga&cd=caeyacoumtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mteygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcngcalj2l2089xqyzdr5clovuuvafq', 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/03/sleep-tracking-ring-oura-raises-20-million-from-michael-dell-lance-armstrong-and-others/&ct=ga&cd=caeyasoumtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mteygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcng8wdz35c5krnjcnypbw21b0pihfg', 'https://www.google.com/alerts/remove?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mte&s=ab2xq4j8dtcluvhhgyayaorwyeut2bkvyp4mrac', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mte', 'https://www.google.com/alerts?source=alertsmail&hl=en&gl=us&msgid=mtqxotu0mdi1mjkxndk4otc1mte']
```

Comment: I am getting output like this <filter object at 0x00000218F2CA9FD0>

Comment: @Rahul edited to match python 3 - use `result = list(filter(interesting, candidates))`

Comment: I am getting the entire links in the array. Its not filtering. I have updated the input and output. Can you check once again

Comment: @Rahul In your updated question, all the input links in the example which don't appear in the expected output contain digits, which according to the question should be included. Is there a more specific filter you're trying to apply?

Comment: ... For example, `'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/atomicos-fourth-state-of-the-european-tech-report-highlights-lots-of-rosy-numbers-but-also-a-discrimination-problem/&ct=ga&cd=caeybioumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnfcgwt_rwsya4ulxw6im7mcy0a74q'` appears in the input but not the expected output, yet it contains numbers.

Comment: I got the issue. I have an example "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/freeletics-raises-45m-for-its-ai-powered-fitness-coach/&ct=ga&cd=caeybcoumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcneh-xmavwlbin0hfswkmrbniousnw"

I want this to get selected because it has 45m which indicates 45 millions

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You mean that the numbers (/ other relevant terms you're looking for) are only interesting if they appear in the last section of the URL path?

Comment: Can you please explain why `'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/atomicos-fourth-state-of-the-european-tech-report-highlights-lots-of-rosy-numbers-but-also-a-discrimination-problem/&ct=ga&cd=caeybioumtm0mjyxmzezntg2oti0nju0odgygjg0n2i3ogq3nmi1owu1yjk6y29tomvuolvt&usg=afqjcnfcgwt_rwsya4ulxw6im7mcy0a74q'` should be filtered out (even though it contains digits?)

Comment: No. I am looking for a number followed by 'm' which means millions in the url string. For reference 'https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/04/freeletics-45m-for-its-ai-powered-fitness-coach/'

In this url we dont have any of the matching string that we have entered but I need this url as it has 45m in the url which indicates 45 million

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184746/discussion-between-andersource-and-rahul).